# Retrieve Apache configuration at directory

Tags: apache, settings, local

Is there some command to retrieve the Apache settings applicable to a certain directory in other words the command should take into account the cascade of `.htaccess` files as well as the global configuration of the Apache server.

The command should do something like:

```
$ command .
AddType text/html html
...
```

Such `command` can be useful to debug why a certain page generates a **500** (or other) error. Since several configuration files can play their part in this.

Comment: There is no way of doing what you have asked. Only via logfiles and rewrite troubleshooting you'll be able to find your problems. On the other side, error 50x generally means your backend has problems, or your proxy is not properly configured.

Comment: @Marcel: but implicitly, Apache will calculate this? Thus it would require "minimal effort" to offer this utility as a command....

Comment: "minimal effort" is a lot of effort in this case. From what I know, the only way I would tackle this requirement of yours, would be to read apache's source code and track where it loads configuration file, and when a request arrive, how it applies config to any request, then create the log you want. That's the power of open source, but it is by no means "minimal effort".

Comment: @Marcel: I don't mean an effort of a "foreign" programmer. But one would expect that Apache would make such tools available. As most compiler designers make debuggers available as well...

Comment: The higher the expectation, the higher the frustration. There is no such tool that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer NO, but you can see what rewrite rules are being applied to requests, that's assuming you have access to the servers httpd.conf and the ability to restart the web server. Simply add the following to your virtual host definition / included rewrite file e.g.

```
RewriteLog "/tmp/tmp_rewrite.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

Remember to remove / comment out the entry, or to set the RewriteLogLevel to 0 once you've finished playing.

Comment: Rewrite rules are of course one part of the "environment configuration", but others are mimetypes, handlers, cgi-scripting,...

Comment: The debug tools in your browser will reveal the assigned header / mime type, but again per my post above there is nothing currently in place to give you what you ask.